# how to send NSMutable array of object(model) to another view and bind it with the NSTableView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I know the question I have asked is kind of confusing so let me first introduce you with the scenario.

**There are 2 *windows*:**

1. A window (Named **DataFetcher**) that contains a *NSButton*. On the button click some data will be fetch from the server and get stored in a *NSMutableArray* and that array will be passed to the next window that will bind the array will *NSTableView*
2. A window(Named: **DataViewer**) that contains NSTableView

**What I have done as yet:**

I have created a *NSMutableArray* (Named: **DataList**) at **DataViewer** On **DataFetcher** window's button click I am retrieving some data from server and feeding the data in **DataList** of **DataViewer** object. Then binding that data to the NSTableView.

**Problem:**
its not working the way I mentioned above. Please help and please let me know how do I do it..

**Code is given below:**

**Window: DataFetcher** *On Button Action*

```
[dataFecherObj setDataList:myNSMutableArray];
[dataFecherObj showWindow:self];
```

**Window: DataViewer**

```
-(void)awakeFromNib{ 
     list = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i = 0; i < [_DataList count]; i++) {
        ScanDigInfoForTable* item = (ScanDigInfoForTable*)[_DataList objectAtIndex:i];
        [list addObject:item];
    }

    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

My pardon for my coding style. I am still new to Obj-C and Cocoa

Comment: You are not following MVC. You should not be storing data in the view classes.

Comment: what should I do? Please guide @trojanfoe

Comment: Read about MVC.  it's used extensively with Cocoa code.